# Take BOSS to a SHOW, but quickly

Tags: word, lateral-thinking, word-ladder

Start with the word BOSS

Change one letter to get another word.

Change another letter and you will get the SHOW (the word SHOW that is)!

Can you do it that quickly?

No rearranging letters.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First, you need to

> change the B to an M to get MOSS.

How do you get from that to "SHOW" by changing only one letter? Simple:

> change the first S to an H (i.e. MOHS) and then rotate the whole word 180 degrees.

Easy!

Comment: That is F___  Krazy fast.

Comment: How is this not "rearranging letters"? (Criticism for the question, not the answer)

Comment: @DavidMcKee: It can be seen as rearranging the point-of-view, rather than the letters themselves. For example, if you do it with cards on a table, you don't need to rotate the cards, you can just walk to the other side of the table.